# read a file with 2 dimensional data and store them into an array (this is my first time using c)

Tags: c, arrays

```
int main() {
    int i;int j;char c;double num;
    double point[65][2];
    FILE *myfile;
    myfile = fopen("point.txt","r");
    if(myfile == NULL)
    {
        printf("can not open file\n");
    }
    else{
        for(i=0;i<65;i++){
            for (j=0; j<2; j++) {
                fscanf(myfile, "%lf", &num);
                point[i][j]=num;
                printf("%lf",point[i][j]);

            }
        }
    }
    fclose(myfile);
}
```

I don't know why it always gives me an empty array. There are 65 observations in the data. That's why I create a 65x2 array.

The file looks like this:

1.87046225914495   0.37205807606083

1.51453361512525   0.45942874936008

..

..

Comment: You should check `return` of `fscanf` . And also please show bit of format of file .

Comment: Can you post your point.txt?

Comment: I just changed the 65 to a 14 lines file and it worked fine. My point.txt file: http://pastebin.com/NqtU0a3a

Comment: what does mean "it gives me an empty array"? Whatever you do or not the `printf` *will* print a value (garbage or 0s).

Comment: I mean it gave me a bunch of zeros, when I used printf.

Comment: I filled a file with these values (repeated 65 times) and run this code and it works fine. As said in my answer check for `fscanf` returned value (is it really always returning 1?). If no check your file (i.e. is it really a text file? No control characters? Does it comes from a text editor, not a document editor such as Word?).

Answer (score 0):

I can't see any error on this code. It can whatever be changed a little:

- you can directly call `fscanf` onto the target value (`fscanf(myfile, "%lf", &(point[i][j]));`)
- if your file format will always be X*2 values you can remove the second `for` loop and read both values (`fscanf(myfile, "%lf%lf", &(point[i][0]), &(point[i][1]));`)
- you should print the table content after reading, so that you are sure to print the final values (if, let say, you overwrite some values at one point)

My only guess would be related to file format. If `scanf` failed to read values (not enough values, bad-formated file…) you will not get results.

As stated by @ameyCU you must check for `fscanf` returned value. It returns the number of "tokens" successfully read. You should check it is really ==1, else it means that format is not good (or no data available in file). In this case content of part or all of your table is undefined (and depending on OS can be filled with 0s).

Edit: if you really have 65x2 values in this file check for invalid characters, i.e. if you used Word or similar to create the data file.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Solution to your Problem,Try to read and understand the code.Basically, the idea what you have is correct but I corrected your code where you made the mistakes. The main working to the solution is in the `while()` loop. So go through it.

```
#include<stdio.h>
//#pragma warning(disable : 4996)


int main() 
{
         int i=0, in = 0; 
         int j=0, jn = 0; 
         int numberOfCol = 0;

         double num1,num2;
         double point[65][2];
         FILE *myfile=NULL;

         myfile = fopen("test.txt", "r");
         if (myfile == NULL)
         {
            printf("can not open file\n");
         }
         else 
         {
           while (!feof(myfile))
           {
               fscanf(myfile, "%lf %lf", &num1, &num2);//since your file contains two numbers per row you need two variables to store the values
               point[i][j] = num1;//At this point (i=0,j=0) you will get the first value of in the row/line. 
               printf("%lf ", point[i][j]);
               ++j;//incremet j so that you move the index to next column i.e (i=0,j=1)
               point[i][j] = num2;//store the second column value of the row/line
               numberOfCol++;
               printf("%lf", point[i][j]);
               printf("\n");
               ++i;//go to next row/line 
               j = 0;//set back the column index to 0 aka the first column index            
            }//Repeat this process till you reach End of file
          }

    fclose(myfile);
    printf("File Data..\n");
    for (in = 0; in<i; in++) 
    {
       for (jn = 0; jn<numberOfCol; jn++)
       {
          printf("%lf ",point[in][jn]);
       }
       printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**EDIT:Here is a modified code consisting of the checking conditions suggested by hexasoft in the comments.Thanks Hexasoft**

```
#include<stdio.h>
//#pragma warning(disable : 4996)


int main() 
{
    int i=0, in = 0; 
    int j=0, jn = 0; 
    int numberOfCol = 0;

    double num1,num2;
    double point[65][2];
    int result;
    FILE *myfile=NULL;

     myfile = fopen("test.txt", "r");
     if (myfile == NULL)
     {
        printf("can not open file\n");
     }
     else 
     {

        while (i<65)//65 or how may ever rows/lines of data you have in your file
        {
            result=fscanf(myfile, "%lf %lf", &num1, &num2);

            if (result == 2)
            {
                point[i][j] = num1;
                printf("%lf ", point[i][j]);
                ++j;
                numberOfCol = j+1;

                point[i][j] = num2;
                printf("%lf", point[i][j]);
                printf("\n");
                ++i;
                j = 0;
            }
            else
            {
               printf("Format Error!\n");
            }

            if (feof(myfile))
            {
                printf("End of file reached!\n");
                break;
            }

    }

}

fclose(myfile);
printf("File Data..\n");
for (in = 0; in<i; in++) 
{
    for (jn = 0; jn<numberOfCol; jn++) 
    {
        printf("%lf ",point[in][jn]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Well, I can't figure in what you find "Solution to (the) Problem". Your `while` if fine, but if enough data is available in input file it will not change anything (compared to `for` loop). Worse, if more than 65x2 data is present you will insert data after `point` end (so UB). And checking for `feof` is not enough as it is raised *after* a failed read. As you don't check `fscanf` return you will have undefined values.

Comment: @hexasoft Thanks for the suggestions about the checking conditions.I added them.